# What js script get External Link with timer will be Re-Directed the Outbound URL to be shown inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, redirect, iframe, outbound, external-links

I have this 3 Files, the *File#1* : *"Links.html"* has courtesy links to externals Domains URL

```
<html>
<title>File#1 - Directory of Links of Externals Domains_URL - Links.html<title>
<body>
<div>
Visit this Web Encyclopedia to expand your knowledge:
 <a href="Free.org/good-bye.html?link=en.wikipedia.org">wikipedia</a> 
<br>
Visit the <a href=
"Free.org/good-bye.html?link=http:/www.WebMasters.StackExChange.com">
 StackExChange</a>to get right people for right answers !
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The *file#2* : *"good-bye.html"* is a "Goodbye page Come Back Soon" with (2) two JavaScripts. . .

The *script#1* show the user a created external-URL-link as an option of click that link, instead of have a delay and wait 15secs. to time-out to be re-directed from *script#2* . . . to the final *window.location externalURL OutBound Domain*

```
<html>
<title>File#2 - Open and External URL link - good-bye.html</title>
<body>
<div>Good Bye ! - ComeBack Soon !</div>

<script language="Javascript">
<!--
  var loc=document.location.toString();
  if (loc) {
    var pos=loc.indexOf('link=');
    if (pos>0) {
      document.write('Click the link to visit the External URL location! <a href="'+loc.substring(pos+5)+'" >  '+loc.substring(pos+5)+' </a> ');
    } else
      document.write('(no location defined)');
  }
// -->
</script>


<div style="display:none;">
~~ The Second Script is a timmed 15-25secs. Automated Re-direction by JS Re-Director ~~~
</div>

<script language="Javascript">   
<!--
var targetURL=" @@ What is the variable that should be HERE? instead of this TEXT has to be Replaced with VariableURL window.location.href or something I don't Know ! This is the script2 Please Help me to Insert the correct variable from script1  @@ "

var currentsecond=15; // waiting time to help visitor to decide to comeback to Free.org
function countredirect(){
if (currentsecond!=1){
currentsecond-=1
document.getElementById('timer').value=currentsecond;
}
else{
window.location=targetURL;
return
}
setTimeout("countredirect()",1000)
}

countredirect();
  }


//-->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

- 1 * (?) What is the *VariableURL* that is mentioned in the *script#1* that is going to "feed" the *script#2* that for now I have an empty line. . . **var targetURL= "  "**

Q#1:    **var targetURL="** @@ What is the variable that has to go HERE ? ~~ instead of this TEXT has to be Replaced with *VariableURL window.location.href* or something I don't Know ! This is the *script#2* Please Help me to Insert the correct variable from *script#1*  @@ "

- 2 * (?) Can you please insert the variableURL inside an iFrame in *File#3* ? ~~ When the 15 secs time runs out... the *File#3*, *"come-back-Top-navBar.html"* should be opened with the external-Domain-URL inside an iFrame ~~ I want an iFrame on that *File#3* show the external link to external Domain, en.wikipedia.org, stackexchange.com, or any link from *File#1* (The Directory of externals URLs).

Q#2: If you know what variable goes to feed. populate, the *script#2* line **var targetURL=" "** ? What is  the variable that is mentioned in script#1 ? I want to put a timer to delay the opening of File#3.
The visitor is going to be redirected after a delay. My *File#3* is a [div][/div] and an [iFrame][/iFrame]

Q#3: Can you show me how the same variable=External-Link-Outbound-URL is inserted in the iFrame of the *File#3* ?. . . ( so the visitor will see the External-Link-Outbound-URL inside the iFrame).

I need to know the js Codes that fix the *Script#2* of *File#2*

I need to know the *iframe Codes* that need to be inserted in the *File#3*

Thank you for your patience !!

Following is my *File#3*, that is incomplete because I don't know the variable(link-OutboundURL) that complete the Dereferer cycle, starting with a clicked link in *File#1* delayed in *File#2* finally to be shown and displayed inside an iFrame in *File#3*

```
<html>
<body>
<tile>File#3 Visit other's URL but comeback to us! comeback-Top-navBar.html</title>
<div height=20>Comeback to Free.org <a href=http://www.Free.org>click here</a></div>
<br>        
        <iframe id="external-url-iframed" width="100%" scrolling="no" 
    frameborder="0" class="external-url-iframedt_iframe" height="80%"> @@ this TEXT 
has to be Replaced with a JavaScript or variableURL-links 
~~ so the user can enjoy my recommended external domains sites under 
an small  TopnavBar Banner @@ </iframe>
        </body>
     </html>
```

- 3 * (?) Can you show me other solutions ? Links to Forums or Tutorials ? Thank You a Lot !
- 4 * (?) What is the *variableString-Windows-Location-ExternalURL* that pass from *File#1* to *File#3* ?

I tested... **var targetURL="***link=***"**  . . . also  . . .**var targetURL="***document.location.toString();***"** but didn't work!

Untill now, if the person doesn't want to wait, and do click on = *File#2* this goes straight to my *File#3* called by *script#1* as *http://free.org/comeback-Top-navBar.html#external-url-iframed* 
 but this Does Not shows and never reach the *Destination-external-Link-OutboundURL-Domainand*

In the other hand, if the person visitor decide or wants to wait. . . the &script#2* timer runs-out, but doesn't go nowhere!

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want.

Question 1: In file #2 you have the following code

```
<script language="Javascript">
<!--
  var loc=document.location.toString();
  if (loc) {
    var pos=loc.indexOf('link=');
    if (pos>0) {
      document.write('Click the link to visit the External URL location! <a href="'+loc.substring(pos+5)+'" >  '+loc.substring(pos+5)+' </a> ');
    } else
      document.write('(no location defined)');
  }
// -->
</script>
```

I think you need to move your `var targetURL=` up to this section.

```
<script language="Javascript">
<!--
    var targetURL = '';
    var loc = document.location.toString();
    var pos = loc.indexOf('link=');

    if (loc && pos>0) {
        targetURL = loc.substring(loc.indexOf('link=')+5);
        document.write( 
            'Click the link to visit the External URL location! ' + 
            '<a href="come-back-Top-navBar.html?link='+escape(targetURL)+'">' + targetURL + '</a>'
        );
    } else {
        document.write('(no location defined)');
    }
// -->
</script>
```

For the second `script` section

```
<script language="text/javascript">   
<!--
    //targetURL already defined
    var currentsecond=15; 

    function countredirect() {
        if (currentsecond!=0) {
            currentsecond -= 1;
            document.getElementById('timer').value=currentsecond;
        } else {
            window.location=targetURL;
            return;
        }
        setTimeout("countredirect()",1000)
    }

    countredirect();
//-->
</script>
```

For question #2, in the second `script` section, instead of doing

```
window.location = targetURL;
```

Do this instead

```
window.location = "come-back-Top-navBar.html?link=" + escape(targetURL);
```

In your file #3, do something like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>File#3 Visit other's URL but comeback to us! comeback-Top-navBar.html</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div height=20>Comeback to Free.org <a href=http://www.Free.org>click here</a></div>
    <br>        
    <iframe id="external-url-iframed" src="" width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" class="external-url-iframedt_iframe" height="80%">
    </iframe>

    <script language="Javascript">
    <!--
        var targetURL = '';
        var loc = document.location.toString();
        var pos = loc.indexOf('link=');

        if (loc && pos>0) {
            document.getElementById("external-url-iframed").src = targetURL;
        } else {
            alert('(no location defined)');
        }
    // -->
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```